# Namespacing issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class `A` in module `M` like below

```
  Module M
    class A
       def method1
          # how to instantiate a model having same name as A
          #like A.first
       end
     end
  end
```

In my models I have a class `A`

```
 class A < ActiveRecord::Base
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the global scope using the `::` operator, e.g:

```
 Module M
    class A
       def method1
          ::A.first
       end
     end
  end
```

Comment: @tsv Just for your info :-
Constants defined within a class or module may be accessed unadorned anywhere within the class or module. Outside the class or module, they may be accessed using the scope operator, ::'' prefixed by an expression that returns the appropriate class or module object. Constants defined outside any class or module may be accessed unadorned or by using the scope operator::'' with no prefix.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your suggestion